# Exporting rigged game characters to a game engine

Tags: modeling, rigging, export, unity

If I created a game character using Blender and it is rigged using the bones, lets say the bone was sticking out of the game character. if I exported the entire model to Unity, would the bones be visible at all?

Comment: bones are only used for deforming the mesh, and are not visible in rendering (game engine or otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bones used in rigging are not normally visible in any end product, be it a game or animation or whatever.
Most (all?) renders and game engines will not render them in the final product, although you may see them in the editor for the game engine (e.g. unity editor while making the game, but not the actual game itself).

Comment: @Jack232 Don't just thank in the comments, consider upvoting the answer, or if it solved your problem mark it as accepted.